# Parceler class not generating error in Android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, parcel, parceler

I have a core branch where following dependencies is decalared

```
implementation "org.parceler:parceler-api:$rootProject.ext.parcelVersion"
annotationProcessor "org.parceler:parceler:$rootProject.ext.parcelVersion"
```

I am declaring a dependency in one of my library module as below

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(':core')
}
```

Here is the class that I will be parceling in my activity

```
@Parcel(parcelsIndex = false)
public class MyClass {
   @SerializedName("validation")
   public String myField;
}
```

Exception is thrown at the third line.

```
 MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
 myClass.myField = "bjbskas";
 Parcelable parcelable =Parcels.wrap(myClass);
```

Exception reads as shown below

```
Unable to find generated Parcelable class for com.example.mylibrary.MyClass, 
verify that your class is configured properly and that the Parcelable class 
com.example.mylibrary.MyClass$$Parcelable is generated by Parceler.
```

If I try putting the parceler library in my library module directly, it gives me another error called

```
Program type already present: org.parceler.Parceler$$Parcels$1
```

Comment: Replace `implementation "org.parceler:parceler-api:$rootProject.ext.parcelVersion"` with `api "org.parceler:parceler-api:$rootProject.ext.parcelVersion"`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried that, I am getting the same exception.

Comment: You might need to also put `annotationProcessor "org.parceler:parceler:$rootProject.ext.parcelVersion"` in both `build.gradle` files. `api` allows your runtime library to be a transitive dependency, but I'm not sure how to make an annotation processor be a transitive dependency.

Comment: @CommonsWare doing that solves the problem while debugging but if I try to make project or create APK it gives me the error 'Program type already present: org.parceler.Parceler$$Parcels$1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the version of Parceler library from `1.0.4` to `1.1.10` solved the problem. I don't know what is the reason behind this but I guess it may be because of some transitive dependencies using version `1.1.10`